# Integer thousands separator in add node form

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I need to place thousands separator on integer field type in add node form when the user is typing a number in the field. Is there any module or quick solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can quickly and easily build a custom module around this:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id="input">
</form>

<script>
    jQuery('#input').keyup(function (event)
    {
        var value = jQuery('#input').val();

        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        var newvalue = value.replace(/,/g, '');   
        var valuewithcomma = Number(newvalue).toLocaleString('en');   
        jQuery('#input').val(valuewithcomma); 
    });
</script>
```

adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883342/add-commas-to-a-number-in-jquery)

**EDIT**

This code has been modified and works in Bartik theme, using an Article content type with an integer field 'number' - it simply resets the value of the input and strips the commas before the form is submitted to the server:

```
<script>
    jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-field-number input').keyup(function (event)
    {
        var value = jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-field-number input').val();

        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        var newvalue = value.replace(/,/g, '');   
        var valuewithcomma = Number(newvalue).toLocaleString('en');   
        jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-field-number input').val(valuewithcomma); 
    });

    jQuery('.node-article-form').submit(function()
    {
        var text = jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-field-number input').val();
        var newtext = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        {
            var c = text.charAt(i);
            if (c != ',')
            {
                newtext += c;
            }
        }
        jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-field-number input').val(newtext);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when he/she saves the content, those characters will be saved, yes?

Comment: it should yes, it is changing the value in the same way as a keypress would

Comment: I just ran a quick test - the field has to be text, not an integer, but otherwise it works as expected - so you may want to look at something else if that is a problem. Perhaps a currency field ignoring the prefix

Comment: since a comma is a string character, not a number character - I don't think you will be able to do it on the fly without using a text field. Validation will always fail on an integer. If it's for display purposes only, then a currency field will work. You could also create your own field widget with it's own validation function - then strip the extra comma(s) out of the value before saving

Comment: Unfortunately the customer asked me to add this feature to the website after finishing the project. So I can't change the field. Maybe I have to modify the node submit validation

Comment: see my edit....